# LottieAlertDialog DialogTypes.TYPE_CUSTOM cannot resolved

Tags: dialog, android-alertdialog, lottie

**error**:

> `com.labters.lottiealertdialoglibrary.DialogTypes` cannot resolve `TYPE_CUSTOM`

**how to produce error**

1. configure settings.gradle (adding `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`)
2. adding  `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to top-level build.gradle
3. import dependencies implementation `'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'` and `implementation 'com.github.mayuce:LottieAlertDialog:1.1'`
4. using `LottieAlertDialog.Builder(this,DialogTypes.TYPE_CUSTOM,"lottie_file.json")`

**android studio version**: Arctic fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2
**build:gradle version**: 7.0.2

[image: error screenshot]

I also added issue on https://github.com/mayuce/LottieAlertDialog/issues/13#issue-988414541

Answer (score 0):

So, I solve this issue.
just put json to assets and rename to each type like error.json and etc